# Wifi not connecting in Alienware laptop with Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I am not sure if this is an hardware issue or software. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 (only OS installed) and tried to connect to wifi. After connecting to wifi, the internet is available briefly and then not available forever. I tried `ping google.com` and following is the output obtained:

```
samh@Alienware-x15-R1:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (142.250.189.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sfo03s25-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.189.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=28.6 ms
64 bytes from sfo03s25-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.189.196): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=30.0 ms
64 bytes from sfo03s25-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.189.196): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=29.8 ms
64 bytes from sfo03s25-in-f4.1e100.net (142.250.189.196): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=30.8 ms
```

After this, it is stuck indefinitely without internet (but wifi connected). Sometimes I get this:

```
samh@Alienware-x15-R1:~$ ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

The wifi network does not have any issues on my phone. I also tried creating a hotspot with my phone and connected the laptop to my phone wifi and it works fine without any issue.